# Detect if macOS version is a beta release

Tags: macos, cocoa, foundation, appkit

I know about the various ways to check the OS version like `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion]`, `Gestalt`, `NSAppKitVersionNumber`, etc.

However these methods don't tell me whether a specific OS version is a beta or a stable release.

Is there a reliable way to detect if the current OS version is a beta release without hardcoding version numbers?

The reason I'm looking into a way to detect this is to notify users of my app of potential incompatibilities when running a macOS beta.

Comment: This is probably unsafe, but you could check if the Feedback app (which is bundled only with beta releases) exists..

Comment: @mangerlahn hmm I was under the impression that only the public betas contain the feedback app but not the developer previews, no?

Comment: I just checked and I still have the Feedback Assistant on my machine even though I'm running the final/non-beta version of 10.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

macOS beta build numbers end in an alpha character.

- Non-Beta Example: Ventura 13.5.1, Build 22G90
- Beta Example: Ventura
  13.4.1 (c), Build 22F770820d
- Beta Example: Sonoma 14.0, Build 23A5312d

```
    #!/bin/sh

    version=$(/usr/bin/sw_vers -buildVersion | /usr/bin/sed -e 's/\(^.*\)\(.$\)/\2/')
    
    if [[ "${version}" =~ [0-9] ]]; then
        echo "Not Beta"
    else
        echo "Beta"
    fi
    
    exit
```